# Why do we care about maximal atlases?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}$ a smooth atlas. $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}$ is maximal if for all $(U,\phi)$ as above satisfying (6), then $(U,\phi) \in \{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}$

where (6) is:

Let X be a topological space and $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}$ a smooth atlas. Let $(U,\phi)$ be such that $U \subset X$ is open, $\phi:U \rightarrow V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a homeomorphism, such that

$$\phi \ \circ \ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}, \ \ \ \phi_{\alpha} \ \circ \ \phi^{-1}  \text{are $C^{\infty}$ where defined.}$$

Then $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\} \cup \{(U,\phi)\}$ is again an atlas.

Why do we care about maximal atlases. Surely this almost trivially always exists? Surely we should care more about minimal atlases (just like in GMT where we care about minimal coverings). Furthermore, why can one easily show the uniqueness of a maximal atlas?

Comment: I edited the tags because this is not really a general topology question: it is about a structure on top of a topological manifold (the smooth structure, aka, the equivalence class of smooth atlas).

Comment: @MikeMiller that is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It trivially always exists when a smooth atlas exists at all (which is not guaranteed).

2) It is often convenient in practice to say "maximal atlas" so that one may choose whatever chart they like for computations, as opposed to one of a pre-ordained set of charts.

3) Given an atlas $\mathcal A$, and two maximal atlases $\mathcal A_i$ containing $\mathcal A$, the union $\mathcal A_1 \cup \mathcal A_2$ is again an atlas, and hence must coincide with both $\mathcal A_1$ and $\mathcal A_2$ by maximality.

4) **We do not really care about these.** This is just a matter of defining what a smooth manifold (and smooth maps between them) are. You could do that just as well by saying that a smooth structure is an equivalence class of atlases, or that it's defined by what the smooth functions $U \to \Bbb R$ for open subsets $U \subset M$. Whatever choice you do works more or less the same as the others. In the end, we care about the topology and geometry of smooth manifolds, not whatever particular choice of definition we used.

Comment: To rephrase #2, the set of maximal atlases on a topological manifold is in bijection with the set of smooth structures, whereas different choices of (nonmaximal) atlas can determine the same smooth structure. Thus, a nonmaximal atlas determines extra structure on a manifold that we generally neither need nor want.

Comment: @Travis That is a good phrasing. Thanks for adding it.

Comment: Cheers. And +1 for the great answer, by the way (especially the meditation in #4).

Comment: @Travis Certainly. I think it is an important point. In my experience, students often get hung up on the technicalities of their favorite flavor (most commonly, maximal atlases) before they get a chance to do anything with them; I would encourage people to learn how to stop worrying and love the smooth structure.